# giblib error: Can't open X display on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash, scripts

I am trying to execute below bash script with cron which getting `giblib error: Can't open X display. It *is* running, yeah?` error.

Bash Script:

```
#!/bin/sh
export DISPLAY=:0 
fnm='/tmp/'$(date +%m.%d.%y_%H.%M.%S)'.png'
echo $fnm
scrot -q 10  $fnm
scp $fnm admin@192.168.1.2:/tmp
```

Crontab :

```
*  *    * * *   admin   bash /autoscreenshot.sh >> /tmp/error.txt 2>> /tmp/error2.txt
```

Error:

```
# cat /tmp/error2.txt
giblib error: Can't open X display. It *is* running, yeah?
```

Anyone have idea about this error ?

Comment: is imagemagick installed? Check with `apt policy imagemagick`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DISPLAY=:0 scrot
```

Declare display for scrot.
For more info [view this](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=33856) topics.

Comment: Note to self: it's a `:`, not a `.`!